# Draw blurred rectangles using mouse events

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Below code just draws rectangles, whenever mouse is dragged, but I want to blur only rectangle region that is drawn from mouse.

```py
import cv2
import argparse

ref_point = []


def shape_selection(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ref_point, crop

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ref_point = [(x,y)]


    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        ref_point.append((x,y))
        #cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(9,9),0)
        cv2.rectangle(image,ref_point[0],ref_point[1],(0,255,0),2)
        #cv2.GaussianBlur(images,(9,9),0)
        cv2.imshow("image",image)

ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--image",required=True,help="Path to image")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
clone=image.copy()
#cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(9,9),0)
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image",shape_selection)

while True:
    cv2.imshow("image",image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("r"):
        image=clone.copy()
    elif key == ord("c"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main "trick" is to use the `GaussianBlur` method just on the region of interest (ROI) of the image. Accessing rectangular ROIs in "Python OpenCV images" is done by proper NumPy [array indexing and slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). Operations solely on these ROIs are supported by most OpenCV functions (Python API).

So, that might be a modified version of your `shape_selection` method:

```py
def shape_selection(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global image, ref_point

    if (event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN):
        ref_point = [(x, y)]

    elif (event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP):
        (x_ref, y_ref) = ref_point[0]

        if (x_ref > x):
            (x, x_ref) = (x_ref, x)
        if (y_ref > y):
            (y, y_ref) = (y_ref, y)

        image[y_ref:y, x_ref:x] = cv2.GaussianBlur(image[y_ref:y, x_ref:x], (9, 9), 0)
        image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x_ref, y_ref), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('image', image)
```

If you draw rectangles "from right to left" or "from bottom to top", the `x` and `y` coordinates of the two recorded points must be swapped for a proper slicing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @HansHirse , thanks im able to blur particular region as required, also in your code how can i show the rectangle area that is blurred(draw a rectangle around blurred region)

Comment: @SiddanthShaiva Ah, I forgot that, sorry. Also, the `image` must be global. That was missing, too. Please see my edited answer.