# How to whiten out or blur all regions outside a rectangle in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

The below code draws a rectangle in an image using mouse events, but I want to whiten out or blur all regions that are outside of the rectangle. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import cv2
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ref_point = []

def shape_select(event,x,y,flags,param):
   global ref_point, crop,image

   if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
      ref_point = [(x,y)]

   elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
      (x_ref,y_ref) = ref_point[0]

      if (x_ref > x):
         (x,x_ref)=(x_ref,x)
      if (y_ref > y):
         (y,y_ref) = (y_ref,y)
      image = cv2.rectangle(image,(x_ref,y_ref),(x,y),(0,255,0),2)
      coord = [(x_ref,y_ref),(x,y)]
      print(coord)
      cv2.imshow("image",image)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--image",required=True, help="path to image")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
clone = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image",shape_select)

while True:
   cv2.imshow("image",image)
   key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
   if key == ord("r"):
      image = clone.copy()
   elif key == ord("c"):
      break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you blur the original image and copy back non blurred Roi ?

Comment: To blur your image use cv2.filter2D or cv2.gaussianblur()

Comment: @Ziri Didnot get you, can you please brief?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [my answer on your similar, earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59044370/11089932), here's a modified version of your `shape_select` method with blurring:

```py
def shape_select(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global image, ref_point

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ref_point = [(x, y)]

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        (x_ref, y_ref) = ref_point[0]

        if x_ref > x:
            (x, x_ref) = (x_ref, x)
        if y_ref > y:
            (y, y_ref) = (y_ref, y)

        temp = image.copy()
        image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (9, 9), 0)
        image[y_ref:y, x_ref:x] = temp[y_ref:y, x_ref:x]
        image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x_ref, y_ref), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('image', image)
```

To whiten out the parts outside the rectangle, replace the last five lines with the following. You then also need to `import numpy as np` as well:

```py
        temp = image.copy()
        image = np.ones_like(image) * 255
        image[y_ref:y, x_ref:x] = temp[y_ref:y, x_ref:x]
        image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x_ref, y_ref), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('image', image)
```

Hope that helps!

---

As requested in the comments, here's the full version I used for testing:

```py
import cv2

ref_point = []


def shape_select(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global image, ref_point

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ref_point = [(x, y)]

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        (x_ref, y_ref) = ref_point[0]

        if x_ref > x:
            (x, x_ref) = (x_ref, x)
        if y_ref > y:
            (y, y_ref) = (y_ref, y)

        temp = image.copy()
        image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (9, 9), 0)
        image[y_ref:y, x_ref:x] = temp[y_ref:y, x_ref:x]
        image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x_ref, y_ref), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('image', image)


image = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
clone = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image",shape_select)

while True:
   cv2.imshow("image",image)
   key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
   if key == ord("r"):
      image = clone.copy()
   elif key == ord("c"):
      break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi @HansHirse, i tried the code but im able to whiten out only after 1 rectangle is drawn, how can i do the same after drawing n numbers of rectangle?

Comment: @SiddanthShaiva You'd need to maintain a (global) list of your rectangles, and then add another case in your `key` switching, e.g. when pressing `w`, the whitening should take place w.r.t. the rectangles in the list. That's certainly more complicated, and not reflected in your question. Feel free to ask a new question, and describe, what you want to achieve in detail, preferably illustrated by some graphic. Nevertheless, leave this question here as is, since it may help future readers.